# Cut long text even without spaces

Tags: css, word-wrap

Is it possible to get a new line when a text is too long, not only on space but on every character?

Example: http://jsbin.com/yaxeyeko/1/edit

Comment: You should know by now...http://i.imgur.com/O5Ifvrw.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Hope i have understood correctly

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/j07bh8gh/)**

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**OR**  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/j07bh8gh/1/)**

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `word-break:break-all`:

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

[**jsbin example**](http://jsbin.com/qapijupi/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div {
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Note: yet this property has a working draft status

Comment: There is no `overflow-wrap` property.

Comment: @j08691 `overflow-wrap` is introduced in CSS3 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: So you recommend using a draft spec property over established properties?

Comment: Depends of your field of application. But you are right. Although I never had any problems in different browser. I edited my answer accordingly. Thank you!